# MySQL: как получить все строки без повторов?

Tags: mysql, select

есть такие записи:

(колонки: Date,Val,Name)

```
2016-02-01 350 A
2016-02-01 360 B
2016-02-02 351 A
2016-02-02 350 B
2016-02-02 350 B
...
```

нужно получить все строки без повторов (когда для каждой даты имя будет уникальным, только 1 раз для каждой даты)... т.е.:

```
2016-02-01 350 A
2016-02-01 360 B
2016-02-02 351 A
2016-02-02 350 B
```

Мой запрос работает не верно:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Date>='2016-01-01' group by Name ORDER BY Date asc, Name asc
```

Comment: Для этого существует distinct. SELECT distinct * FROM myTable WHERE Date>='2016-01-01' group by Name ORDER BY Date asc, Name asc

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко DISTINCT и GROUP BY одновременно - бессмысленны. После группировки все записи уже уникальны. Либо одно, либо другое. Но DISTINCT работает быстрее. К тому же с ним не напорешься на проблему с ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

Answer (score 0):

Определите, что должно выдаваться в поле `Val` при такой выборке. Группируйте по дате и имени. Применяйте соответствующую агрегацию к Val. Например, с `min`:

```
select date, min(val), name from mytable group by date, name
```